# Value not being updated after Callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, callback

I want to update the value of a my deviceData array inside a callback function. From the following code, I can see that deviceData is being updated inside of onResults. However, when I print the array after query.nextAsTwin(onResults) is called, it is empty.

```
async function getDeviceTwin(connectionString) {
    var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

    var query = registry.createQuery('SELECT * FROM devices', 100);
    var deviceData = [];

    var onResults = function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to fetch the results: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            // Do something with the results
            results.forEach(function(twin) {
                console.log(twin);
                const deviceObj = {
                    deviceID: twin.deviceId,
                };
                deviceData.push(deviceObj);
                console.log(deviceData);
            });

            if (query.hasMoreResults) {
                query.nextAsTwin(onResults);
            }
        }
    };

    query.nextAsTwin(onResults);
    console.log("query: ", deviceData);
}
```

I have tried to pass deviceData as a parameter, but that just breaks everything.

```
async function getDeviceTwin(connectionString) {
    var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

    var query = registry.createQuery('SELECT * FROM devices', 100);
    var deviceData = [];

    var onResults = function(deviceData, err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to fetch the results: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            // Do something with the results
            results.forEach(function(twin) {
                console.log(twin);
                const deviceObj = {
                    deviceID: twin.deviceId,
                };
                deviceData.push(deviceObj);
                console.log(deviceData);
            });

            if (query.hasMoreResults) {
                query.nextAsTwin(onResults(deviceData));
            }
        }
    };

    query.nextAsTwin(onResults(deviceData));
    console.log("query: ", deviceData);
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? This code is largely adapted from https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-hub-node/blob/main/samples/twin_query.js.